# Extending IQueryable to modify default query behavior

Tags: sql, entity-framework, extension-methods, iqueryable

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to approach this, so I'm hoping to get a lead on that via this question.

Say I have a database with a certain recurring column in most of the tables. In most (if not all) of my queries I have to filter on this particular column (i.e. checking if it's null).
This leads to alot of '.Where(x => x.Thingy == null)' scattered around the place.

In itself this of course isn't really a problem, but I was wondering if I could tuck this behavior in somewhere 'higher', like in IQueryable, as standard behavior. With the siden ote that in some rare cases the filtering is unwanted. Basically every (part of a) query over a table needs to be extended with 'WHERE thingy IS NULL', interwoven in joins et cetera.

The problem is that I'm really not quite sure where to start. I'm not looking for implementations as I'd rather figure the nitty gritty details out myself.

What I am looking for is a place to start or if this is at all possible.
Is IQueryable the correct way to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply expose a pre-filtered `IQueryable<T>` property:

```
public class ThingContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Thing> Things
   {
      get { return Set<Thing>(); }
   }

   public IQueryable<Thing> ThingsWithoutThingy
   {
      get { return Things.Where(x => x.Thingy == null); }
   }
}
```

Any inserts and un-filtered queries will need to be done on the `Things` property. Any filtered queries should use the `ThingsWithoutThingy` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use extension methods on Thing:

```
public static class ThingExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<Thing> WithoutThingy(this IQueryable<Thing> query)
    {
        return query.Where(x => x.Thingy == null);
    }
}
```

Then you use it like this:

```
Things.WithoutThingy().Select(...)
```